# SharePoint 2013 run Javascript on add item

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I'm looking for a bit of guidance on how to get a JS file to run when a user clicks 'new item' on a list.

I'm currently using:

```
​<script src="Shared%20Documents/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="Shared%20Documents/sputility.min.js"></script>
<script language='javascript'>

var siteUrl = '/cms/';
function retrieveListItems()
{
    //My Code Here
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js"); 
});
```

I've added a Content Editor to the 'Default New Form' and put the link to the file containing the code in the 'Content Link' field.

I'm currently unsure if the code is even executing when a new item is added... Is there something I've missed? Or is this totally the wrong way to go about this?

Comment: If it's SharePoint 2013 or SharePoint online, try JSLink/CSR option, really cool feature to look into.

Answer (score 0):

I usually add a script editor webpart into the default new form and add a link to the script which i place in some subfolder within the style library.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/Scripts/nameofScript.js" ></script>
```

Do not use the implicit closing tag

```
<script ... />
```

This didnt work for me in IE.

To check if the script gets executed at all you can use the developer tools in your browser (usually F12). Alternatively just add an

alert("(>'-')>");

in the beginning.